# How to get wp_editor field content when it is inside a Form?

Tags: plugins, ajax, wp-editor

I am working with a plugin where admin needs to send Email to the user. For Email composing I have used wp_editor inside a FORM and the FOMR submission is handling with an AJAX call.
How can I get the content of the wp_editor field when the form submitted and send to the JS file AJAX.

The FORM is located on a PHP file and here is the code

```
                <div class="email-composer-section">
                <h2>Email Composer</h2>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <?php //wp_nonce_field('compose_email_nonce', 'compose_email_nonce'); 
                    ?>
                    <label for="email_body">Email Body:</label>
                    <?php
                    $settings = array(
                        'textarea_name' => 'email_body',
                        'editor_class' => 'email-body-editor',
                    );
                    wp_editor('', 'email_body', $settings);
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="button email-submit" data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('compose_email_nonce'); ?>" data-inquiry-id="<?php echo $inquiryDetails->ID; ?>" value="Send Email">
                </form>
            </div>
```

This form submission is controlled by an Ajax call and here is the code, I want the wp_editor content will be stored on the 'emailBody' variable here so I can send it to the PHP file and use there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".email-submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

var inquiryId = $(this).data("inquiry-id");
var nonce = $(this).data("nonce");

// Retrieve the content of the wp_editor
//var emailBody = tinyMCE.get("email_body").getContent(); // This is not working, 
 giving Uncaught Type error

var emailBody = "I want to store wp_editor content here";

// Open the email composer modal
openEmailComposer(inquiryId, nonce, emailBody);});

function openEmailComposer(inquiryId, nonce, emailBody) {
// Here we would make an AJAX call to the PHP function handling email composition

$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action: "compose_email",
    nonce: nonce,
    inquiry_id: inquiryId,
    email_body: emailBody,
  },
  success: function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
      // Populate the details div with the response
      // $("#email-composer").html(response.data).show();
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      alert("Error opening email composer.");
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Error opening email composer.");
  },
});
}
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
To retrieve the content of the wp_editor field when the form is submitted and send it via AJAX, you need to make a few adjustments to your JavaScript code. The issue you're encountering with tinyMCE.get("email_body").getContent() is likely due to the timing of when this code is executed or the editor instance not being correctly referenced.

Here's a modified version of your JavaScript code that should correctly retrieve the content from the wp_editor and send it through your AJAX call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".email-submit").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var inquiryId = $(this).data("inquiry-id");
        var nonce = $(this).data("nonce");

        // Retrieve the content of the wp_editor
        var emailBody;
        if (typeof tinyMCE !== 'undefined' && tinyMCE.get('email_body') && !tinyMCE.get('email_body').isHidden()) {
            emailBody = tinyMCE.get('email_body').getContent();
        } else {
            emailBody = $('#email_body').val();
        }

        // Open the email composer modal
        openEmailComposer(inquiryId, nonce, emailBody);
    });

    function openEmailComposer(inquiryId, nonce, emailBody) {
        // AJAX call to the PHP function handling email composition
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "compose_email",
                nonce: nonce,
                inquiry_id: inquiryId,
                email_body: emailBody,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    alert("Error opening email composer.");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error opening email composer.");
            },
        });
    }
});
```

In this modified code, the emailBody variable is set using a conditional statement that checks if the TinyMCE editor is defined and not hidden. If TinyMCE is active, it retrieves the content from the editor; otherwise, it falls back to the standard textarea value. This approach ensures compatibility with different scenarios, such as when TinyMCE is not loaded or when the user is working in the "Text" tab of the editor instead of the "Visual" tab.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much, highly appreciated.
I have another related question. I want to enable HTML code will also support in the email body. I have added 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' insile the Header array but this is not rendering the HTML Style attributes used on the wp_editor, any idea or suggestions please?